# resize an annotation xcode

Tags: ios, uiimageview, mapkit, image-resizing, mkannotationview

i look for resize an image which is used for an annotion.
In fact i have an image (size: 35x63 pxl), but when it appear on the we can see pixels.So i want to put an image with more definition (size: 59x105), but of course it is too big for the map.
Do you know how use the hd image, but reduce the size on the map like the md image ?

Actually i run this code :

```
UIView *leftCAV = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:GCRectake(0,0,23,23)];
annotationView.leftCalloutAccesoryView = leftCAV;
annotationView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"myimage.png"];
annotationView.canShowCallout = YES;
```

Comment: Create a version called `myimage@2.png` in the project?

Comment: it's not the problem, i mean that i want to use an image with a size of 59x105, but display on the screen a smaller image like 35x63. And this just because we can see the pixels for an image with low definition.

Comment: Do you understand about image *scale*?

Comment: I think what @trojanfoe means is `myimage@2x.png` (ie. a retina version of the image that is double-size).  You would still say imageNamed:@"my image.png" but iOS will show the @2x (hi-res) version on retina screens.